# How do you follow up on soap in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, soap

I'm starting to work on a project on java with eclipse IDE, and I understood that there is a plug-in that I can follow the requests and the responds.
I've been looking for them but haven't found anything, if anyone knows, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) for your response/requests, if you have deployed web service on your localhost or anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

[SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a very nice tool. You can download it standalone (I prefer) or you can also download the [Eclipse plugin](http://www.soapui.org/IDE-Plugins/eclipse-plugin.html) for it.

Comment: how is that answer different than mine?

Comment: It is not. Considering we both answered the same min ago I think that explains the duplicate post

Comment: @mtpettyp I think answers on SO are LIFO, you can conclude that easily you see your answer @ the top

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the placement of answers (maybe this has changed since 2010) has to do with your reputation, and not just the timing.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has a built in Web Service explorer that may be enough for your needs.

1. Open the JavaEE Perspective
2. Click "Run", then "Launch the Web Services Explorer"
3. Click the WSDL Page icon in the top right corner
4. Click "WSDL Main" and enter your WSDL URL.

This will allow you to use a UI to enter in your parameter values but also switch back to the raw request and response xml if necessary.